# Ruby call method on all following def calls?

Tags: ruby

I've seen some code that makes a class method such that you can write

```
class_method :instance_method,
```

to alias `instance_method` and call it from in a wrapper method every time it is called. Is there a way to be able to call `class_method` and have it apply to all the following definition calls (like how `private` works)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question. In the future, please provide a specification of what it is exactly that you are trying to do, preferably in the form of an executable testsuite, so that we can check for ourselves whether our answers *really* answer your question.

Are you perhaps talking about something like this?

```
module MethodHook
  private

  def class_method(m=nil)
    return if @__recursing__ # prevent infinite recursion
    return @__class_method__ = true unless m

    @__recursing__ = true

    old_m = instance_method(m)
    define_method(m) do |*args, &block|
      puts "before #{m}(#{args.join(', ')})" # wrap wrap wrap
      old_m.bind(self).(*args, &block)
      puts "after #{m}" # more wrapping
    end

    @__recursing__ = nil
  end

  def method_added(m)
    class_method(m) if @__class_method__
    super
  end
end
```

Use like this:

```
class Foo
  extend MethodHook

  def unwrapped
    puts __method__
  end

  class_method

  def wrapped
    puts __method__
  end
end

f = Foo.new

f.unwrapped
# unwrapped

f.wrapped
# before wrapped()
# wrapped
# after wrapped

class Foo
  class_method(:unwrapped)
end

f.unwrapped
# before unwrapped()
# wrapped
# after unwrapped
```

Comment: Sorry about the vague question, but you definitely got the gist of what I was asking. Thank you